# RequireJS new instance of a module from a string name

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a couple of modules that I want to instantiate the object from a string.
This is usually easy when classes/objects etc are on the global scope `window`

```
new window["MyClass"]()
```

With require JS the modules aren't in the `window` scope and they're not on `this` if within a class.

Do you know what scope I require?

```
define(['testclassb'], function(TestClassB) {
  var TestClassA, testclassa;

  TestClassA = (function() {
    function TestClassA() {
      console.log("A");
      new this["TestClassB"](); #errors with undefined function
      new window["TestClassB"](); #errors with undefined function
      new TestClassB(); #works fine
    }

    TestClassA.prototype.wave = function() {
      return console.log("Wave");
    };

    return TestClassA;

  })();

  testclassa = new TestClassA();
  return testclassa.wave();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a couple of modules that I want to instantiate the object from a string

That's mostly a bad idea and indicates a code smell. Do you really need that?

> Do you know what scope I require?

`TestClassB` is a *local variable*, which is impossible to access by name. Since you are already statically declaring `testclassb` as a dependency, there should be no reason not to use the static variable `TestClassB` as well.

However, require.js allows you to synchronously `require()` already loaded modules, so you could as well use

```
new (require("testclassb"))();
```

Comment: Thanks, Yeh I'm not fond of it tbh, but the object to be instantiated is determined by data send over a socket. So I wanted to avoid a nasty ton of if logic, so I opted for a hash to map the strings to the objects http://pastie.org/7452137

Comment: Yes, that's what you always can do (and what is the right thing in this case) :-)